# Branch of $\arctan(z)$ and calculating $\oint _{A} \arctan(z)\,\rm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

in the context of calculating $\displaystyle \oint _{A} \arctan(z) \,\mathrm dz$ on $\mathbb{C} $\ $[-i,i]$. 
I have a couple of questions:

1) What does it mean to ''satisfy''  $\arctan(1)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. Or to ''take the branch that satisfies  $\arctan(1)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ ''?

2) I thought of calculating $\displaystyle \oint_{A} \arctan(z) dz$ by going in small circles round $i$ and $-i$ and then let the radius of these circles go to zero. Then I need to show that the integral around these small circles is equal to $0$. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.